# How to display all records using struct

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am trying to fetch all data from a table. It returns all data but it is displaying only the last record. I am using GORM and GIN with Golang.

I tried to create a struct and pass that struct to the `Find` method.

```golang
type MpCountry struct{
        id uint
        Iso string
        Name string
        Nicename string
        Iso3 string
        Numcode uint
        phonecode uint
}
```

Code:

```golang
countries:=  DbModel.MpCountry{}
DbModel.DB.Debug().Find(&countries)
fmt.Println(countries)
fmt.Println("test")
log.Printf("%+v", countries)
return  &countries
```

Output

```
SELECT * FROM `mp_countries`
[239 rows affected or returned ]

{id:0 Iso:ZW Name:ZIMBABWE Nicename:Zimbabwe Iso3:ZWE Numcode:716 phonecode:0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing in a struct, not a slice of structs. It is therefore replacing the values in the struct, until it reaches the last record.

Instead, pass in a pointer to a slice:

```golang
countries := &[]DbModel.MpCountry{}
DbModel.DB.Debug().Find(countries)
```

Comment: It works but while returning gives error
 cannot use countries (type *[]DbModel.MpCountry) as type DbModel.MpCountry in return argument

**func GetCountryCodeAndName(DbModel.MpCountry)(
        countries := &[]DbModel.MpCountry{}
        DbModel.DB.Debug().Find(countries)
        fmt.Println(*countries)
        fmt.Println("test")
        return countries
}**

Comment: What's the return type of your function?

Comment: Before you suggested changes above, I was using **DbModel.MpCountry**  but after changing code as per above changes, It give error  **cannot use countries (type *[]DbModel.MpCountry) as type DbModel.MpCountry in return argument**    I tried many things but not able to resolve

Comment: Looks like you're trying to return the slice instead of the single struct that it's expecting. Change the function to return a slice instead.